# Get WMS data using input point layer and store them in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, identify

When I click on a WMS layer using the "Identify" tool, a pop-up window with some data opens.
Can I store these data in a point layer along with the clicked coordinates?
Can I do this automatically, using an input point layer instead of clicking manually?
I imagine a functionality, similar to "Sample Raster Data" for WCS.
I know, a different type of service (WFS) would be more suitable, but I only have WMS available.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to create `getFeatureInfo` URLs for each point you are interested in.

To do this you need 2 things:

1. A Full WMS request (for the base URL)
2. The position in **pixels** of each point in your shapefile

Then all you do is loop through the shapefile creating a `getFeatureInfo` request of each point and save the results.